# Como chamar um aplicativo nativo?

Tags: android

Preciso chamar a calculadora a partir do clique em um botão, como posso fazer isto? Estou tendo dificuldades, sou iniciante em Android e me perdi completamente na implementação deste código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesta postagem http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-intents-for-app-integration-call-a-calculator-play-video-open-an-editor/ encontrei o seguinte código:

Voce tera que usar `Intent`, adicione estas variaveis a sua classe `MyActivity`:

```
private static final String CALCULATOR_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.calculator2";
private static final String CALCULATOR_CLASS_NAME   = "com.android.calculator2.Calculator";
```

Adicione este metodo junto aos demais metodos:

```
public void launchCalculator()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(new Component Name(CALCULATOR_PACKAGE_NAME,
                                            CALCULATOR_CLASS_NAME));

    try {
        this.start Activity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException noSuchActivity) {
        // handle exception where calculator intent filter is not registered
    }
}
```

Voce usar `launchCalculator` no evento click do seu botão, por exemplo:

```
     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ID_DO_SEU_BOTAO);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             launchCalculator(); //Chama o Intent
         }
     });
```

> Faz algum tempo que nao trabalho com Java e Android, posso ter errado algo no codigo, me avise se falhar.

- Leia sobre `Intent`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
- Leia sobre Java: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info
- Exemplos android: http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html

Comment: Rodou redondinho, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

A dificuldade é que alguns fabricantes substituem a calculadora-padrão do Android puro (pacote `com.android.calculator2`) por seus próprios aplicativos, que ficam em um pacote diferente, aí fica difícil adivinhar qual é o pacote da calculadora.

Mas você pode tentar localizar a calculadora-padrão assim:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> items =new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);  
for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {
    if( pi.packageName.toString().toLowerCase().contains("calcul")){
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
        map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
        items.add(map);
    }
}
```

e em seguida pode chamar o aplicativo fazendo:

```
if(items.size()>=1){
    String packageName = (String) items.get(0).get("packageName");
    Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (i != null) {
        startActivity(i);
    } else{
        // Aplicativo não encontrado
    }
}
```

Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662506/how-to-call-android-calculator-on-my-app-for-all-phones)